# Strange Any? as AnyObject behaviour

Tags: swift, casting, option-type, anyobject

I'm struggling to understand the behaviour of the following code:

```
let a: Any? = nil
let b: AnyObject? = a as AnyObject

if let c: AnyObject = b {
    print(c)
    print("That's not right, is it?")
} else {
    print("I'd expect this to be printed")
}
```

When run in a playground, although a is nil, the first closure is executed and prints the following:

> <null>
>   That's not right, is it?

**Q:** How is this possible and is it expected behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a as AnyObject` will cast `a` to `NSNull` so that `b` is not nil

You can check it with `type(of:)`

```
let a: Any? = nil
let b: AnyObject? = a as AnyObject

if let c: AnyObject = b {
    print(c)
    print(type(of: c)) // will print "NSNull"
    print("That's not right, is it?")
} else {
    print("I'd expect this to be printed")
}
```

Comment: Stupid me... "<null>" is the description for an NSNull, long time since I've last had to work with ObjectiveC and I rarely use NSNulls in Swift...

Answer (score 2):

Because `<null>` is not `nil`. `AnyObject` is a type that bridges to Objective-C space.